# doctrine mapping for self referencing class attribute

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a Forum Entity that may contain sub forums which will be of the same class(Forum) . i am having trouble with establishing this relation .

the code below is what i have tried so far in my Forum class

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=5000, nullable=false)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the forum wallpaper as a PNG file.")
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/png" })
 */
private $wallpaper;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="added_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $addedDate;


/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $moderators;

/**
 * @var Forum[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Forum", mappedBy="id", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $subForums;


/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $userId;
```

the problem after updating the database scheme i didnt end up with any table linkin forums and subforums so i am confused how can i add a sub forum to an exsiting forum later on . Any help is much appriciated

[image]

Comment: Can, you show us the table structure that has been generated ?

Comment: i added a screenshot above

Comment: since it's one-to-many, the only way to realize that is by creating a join table (possibly called "sub_forums", but I'm not certain) it would be different for many-to-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a [One-To-Many self-referencing mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing)

So change your `$subForums` like so:

```php
/**
 * @var Forum[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Forum", mappedBy="parentForum", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $subForums;
```

and add `$parentForum`, like so:

```php
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Forum", inversedBy="subForums")
 * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $parentForum;
```

Comment: Yes i believe this is what i am looking for ! thanks for your help , further inverstigation is my part

Comment: Btw do u have any idea how i can delete the forums after applying your method ?  i had a delete action in my controller that used to work just fine but after this change i get  " Notice: Undefined index: parentForum " and the element is not deleted

Comment: Sorry I've made a typo in the code, I've updated it now - the parameter name should be `$parentForum`, not `$parent` as it was.